# get dict from dataframe which rows contains many values?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

**Input**

```
df 

A         B
a         23
b,c       34
d,e,%f    30
```

**Goal**

```
df_dct = {'a':23,'b':34,'c':34,'d':'30','e':'30','f':30}
```

The details as below:

- `A` as keys , `B` as values
- The values in `A` is string and some is grouped by `','`
- The keys comes from by spliting `','` , and should replace all `'%'` and space.

**Try**

- I know using `zip` to get dict from two dataframes but could not handle spliting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for `pandas >= 0.25` with [`df.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
In [32]: df.A = df.A.str.replace("%", "")
In [42]: df_dct = df.assign(var1=df['A'].str.split(',')).explode('var1').drop('A', 1).set_index('var1').to_dict()['B'] 

In [43]: df_dct
Out[43]: {'a': 23, 'b': 34, 'c': 34, 'd': 30, 'e': 30, 'f': 30}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the percentage from column A with [str replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df["A"] = df.A.str.replace("%", "")
```

Use itertools' [product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the pairing of each element in A and B for each row, then combine them into one list, using [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import product, chain
#apply dict to get your final result
dict(chain.from_iterable((product(A.split(","),[B])) for A,B in df.to_numpy()))

{'a': 23, 'b': 34, 'c': 34, 'd': 30, 'e': 30, 'f': 30}
```